# Button Design Android Studio

Tags: android-studio

I'm a beginner in Android Studio and I have some difficulties designing this image: [Image to design](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sOsoe.png)

I did a LinearLayout for the ListView (I kept space for the Send, EditText and Receive Button at the end), and I added another LinearLayout for the "Send" Button with the EditText in between and the "Receive" Button. But when I try to put a button in my second linearLayout, it appears out of my phone design. Here's my code:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical"
tools:context=".ChatRoomActivity"
android:layout_marginBottom="50dp">


<ListView
    android:id="@+id/ListView"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"


<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="50dp"
    android:padding="50dp"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/SendButton"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="31dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="60dp">
</LinearLayout>
```

My question is how to do the part under the ListView? Thank you in advance for the help and explanation, it will help me a lot.

PS: I didn't add the EditText nor the "Receive" Button cause the first "Send" Button isn't showing.

Comment: why not to try constraint layout?

Answer (score 0):

For the second linear layout, you can do as below:

```
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="50dp"
    android:padding="50dp"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
android:weightSum="3"
>

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/SendButton"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="31dp"
 android:layout_weight="1"
        android:text="Send"
        android:layout_marginBottom="60dp">

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/editTextView"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="31dp"
 android:layout_weight="1"
         android:hint="Type Here"
        android:layout_marginBottom="60dp"
    />
 <Button
        android:id="@+id/ReceiveButton"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="31dp"
 android:layout_weight="1"
        android:text="Receive"
        android:layout_marginBottom="60dp">
</LinearLayout>
```